# How to connect Combo Box with Image in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I was just trying to connect the combo box to the Image. This means when I select any option in Combo Box then Combo Box shows me an Image of that Option. Please help me to know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this behavior is to change the image source when the **ComboBox.SelectedItem** is changed by handling the **ComboBox.SelectionChanged event**.

Here is a simple demo of how it works. First of all, create a `ComboBox` control and give it some data about the locations. Then handling the  **ComboBox.SelectionChanged event** in the code behind and get the selected item. Now you could check the selected value and change the source of the image.

**XAML:**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox x:Name="LocationComboBox" Header="Location" Height="60" Width="296" ItemsSource="{x:Bind source}" SelectionChanged="LocationComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:LocationData">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind location}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <Image x:Name="LocationImage" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<LocationData> source { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        source = new List<LocationData>();
        source.Add(new LocationData { location = "london" });
        source.Add(new LocationData { location = "paris" });
        source.Add(new LocationData { location = "seattle" });
        source.Add(new LocationData { location = "vancouver" });
        
    }

    private void LocationComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LocationData data = LocationComboBox.SelectedItem as LocationData;
        switch (data.location)
        {
            case "london":
                LocationImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/london.png"));
                break;
            case "paris":
                LocationImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/paris.png"));
                break;
            case "seattle":
                LocationImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/seattle.png"));
                break;
            case "Rvancouvered":
                LocationImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/vancouver.png"));
                break;
        }
    }
}


public class LocationData
{
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

You could change it based on your own requirenments.

Comment: Its help me more, Thank You ❤

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Combo box and wanted to connect the combo box attribute with Image, So  I followed these steps and found my solution.

**XAML:**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <ComboBox x:Name="imageViewer" Width="200" Header="Picture" PlaceholderText="LifePicture" SelectionChanged="imageViewer_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <x:String>America</x:String>
            <x:String>Bombey</x:String>
            <x:String>China</x:String>
            <x:String>Delhi</x:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <Image x:Name="PictureView" Height="150" Width="150"
           Margin="0,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
       

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
 private void imageViewer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string imageName = imageViewer.SelectedItem.ToString();
       
      
       if(imageName == "America")
        {
            PictureView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/a.jpg"));
        }
       else if (imageName == "Bombey")
        {
            PictureView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/b.jpg"));
        }
        else if (imageName == "China")
        {
            PictureView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/c.jpg"));
        }
        else if (imageName == "Delhi")
        {
            PictureView.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/d.jpg"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Thank you I am trying to explain and I changed.